# Configuring CakePHP .htaccess for Cpanel ~temp/ URL

Tags: url-rewriting, cakephp-2.0, cpanel

I'm trying to set up CakePHP 2.x in Cpanel (Hostmonster) while the domain of the site is still pointing to the older server. In order to pull up the site without the domain (for demo), I have to use http://[hosting-IP-address]/~mysite.

This is my default .htaccess file located in the root (the one before app/ folder):

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]

If I leave it as it is, I get 404 error. When I remove the .htaccess file or leave it blank, the site content loads, but without CSS. The site files are located in /home2/mysite/public_html/ folder. I tried adding RewriteBase with different combinations (~mysite, mysite, mysite/public_html), but no avail.

I have tried with rewrite base setting then i get 500 internal server error. Please suggest

Comment: i'm facing the same issue. It seems that cakephp isn't supported with url's containing the "~" character... Did you solve that anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing your site .htaccess code. I will suggest you update your local pc host file to point your site to new server, so that you can check your all URL.

Open your hosts file which is located at : c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts and add the following code with your new hosting IP address

```
hosting-IP-address www.domain.com
hosting-IP-address domain.com
```